# New Layout between the existing layout

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-layout, android-widget

I have made one Layout in which I want to set the another layout from the existing xml file. Is this possible?

See below code:

```
<TabHost xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:id="@android:id/tabhost"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="fill_parent">
<LinearLayout
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">
    <TabWidget
        android:id="@android:id/tabs"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@android:id/tabcontent"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent">
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textview1"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:text="this is a tab" />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textview2"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:text="this is another tab" />
        <TextView 
            android:id="@+id/textview3"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent" 
            android:text="this is a third tab" />
    </FrameLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Now I want to set the Layout in the frameLayout` 
how it this possible?

Thanks.

Comment: do you want to add layout dynamically (means in activity) ?

Comment: No, I have Created the Both layout in the Xml file, and For the common view of Main Activity i want to use that trick. i want to call another inner view in to the activity calling. . .  how it is Possible ?

Comment: Please check the Question i have updated the Code that i have Given

Answer (score 0):

Just create another activity with your second layout and then start the second activity with `startActivity()`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't provide any code, but if you have 2 layouts in xml and the first one should  include the second one, use the [include-tag](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/layout-tricks-reuse.html).